# Xpath and innerHTML

Tags: html, innerhtml, xpath

What Xpath expression can I use to find all the anchor (just 'a') elements whose actual text (the innerHTML) is Logout.

something like

```
//a[@innerHTML='Logout']
```

Would that be correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it would be incorrect. `innerHTML` is a property, part of the object model, while XPath operates on tags and attributes. Unless your `a` tag actually has an attribute named `innerHTML`, this wouldn't work.

If you want to compare the value of the tag itself, you can use the `.` (dot) to refer to the tag:

```
a[.='Logout']
```

However, I must add, just in case you're using jQuery: I'm not sure if it will work with jQuery. jQuery does not support XPath fully, only basic stuff.

Comment: I'm using objective-c on the iphone using Hpple. I will try it and see if it works. Thanks for your answer :)